# Send mail refuse to send to other port except for 25(default)

Tags: java, email, smtp

i'm very new to this smtp thing..i got an issue..i use smatermail as my server mail to receive and send email...in my client side i got a text box that can change the port for sending email..when i use port 25 its okay..but when i change to another port even the port in smatermail eq 8025 its doesnt want to send the email..its like the server run but not listening to other port except 25..

its show error in the log

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 192.168.56.30, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.mastersam.analyst.compass.engine.mail.Mailer$SenderWorker.run(Mailer.java:150)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:297)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:229)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
    ... 7 more
```

and this is the client side code

```
package com.mastersam.analyst.compass.engine.mail;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.mastersam.analyst.compass.model.ApplicationSettingModel;

/**
 * Sends email updates. Multiple recipient must be semicolon-separated.
 */
public class Mailer {
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Mailer.class);

    private static Mailer self = new Mailer();

    public static Mailer instance() {
    return self;
    }

    /**
     * Sends email alerts to recepient(s).
     * 
     * @param to
     *            (Semicolon-separated if multiple) recipients address
     * @param subject
     * @param content
     *            Must be in textual form.
     */
    public void send(String[] to, String subject, String content)
        throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {

        ApplicationSettingModel setting = ApplicationSettingModel.ThreadLocalSetting
        .get();
    if (setting == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "ApplicationSetting is not bind to current thread.");
    }

    SenderWorker worker = new SenderWorker(setting, to, subject, content);
    worker.start();
    }

    /**
     * Extract name form email address. E.g simon@example.com will return simon.
     */
    private static String getPersonalName(String add) {
    int ind = add.indexOf("@");
    return add.substring(0, ind);
    }

    /**
     * Init SMTP Authenticator
     */
    private static class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    PasswordAuthentication auth;

    public SMTPAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
        auth = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return auth;
    }

    }

    /**
     * Mailer internal class to configure and send SMTP mail
     */
    private static class SenderWorker extends Thread {
    private ApplicationSettingModel setting;
    private String[] to;
    private String subject;
    private String content;

    public SenderWorker(ApplicationSettingModel setting, String[] to,
        String subject, String content) {
        this.setting = setting;
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
    }

    /**
     * configure and return mail message
     * 
     * @param session
     *            javax.mail.Session
     * @return return configured mail message
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws MessagingException
     */
    private Message getMessage(Session session)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException, MessagingException {
        Address[] toRecp = new Address[to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < toRecp.length; i++) {
        toRecp[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i], getPersonalName(to[i]));
        }
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(setting.getSmtpMail(),
            getPersonalName(setting.getSmtpMail())));

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toRecp);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setText(content);
        Date d = new Date();
        msg.setSentDate(d);
        return msg;
    }

    public void run() {
        Properties authProps = new Properties();
        Properties normProps = new Properties();
        Session session = null;
        boolean requireAuth = setting.getSmtpMode().trim()
            .equalsIgnoreCase("Authenticated");
        boolean sent = false;
        authProps.put("mail.smtp.host", setting.getSmtp());
        normProps.put("mail.smtp.host", setting.getSmtp());

        if (requireAuth) {
        authProps.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        session = Session.getInstance(authProps, new SMTPAuthenticator(
            setting.getSmtpUser(), setting.getSmtpPass()));
        try {
            Transport.send(getMessage(session));
            sent = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("run", e);
        }
        }

        if (!sent) {
        session = Session.getInstance(normProps, null);
        try {
            Transport.send(getMessage(session));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("run", e);
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

..i try to find where is the code that make the port is default..can someone help me in this matter and any change that i need to make in the code..thank you n sorry for my english..im still learning it..

Comment: common for hosts to block ports. and this has nothing to do with php

Comment: owh wokeyh thnks bro to remind me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception you can see, that your code is still trying to connect to port 25:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: 192.168.56.30, 25; timeout -1
```

That's because you're not specifying port at all when sending the mail, so the default one (25) is used. If you want to send a mail on a different port you should specify it explicitly just like the host value:

```
authProps.put("mail.smtp.host", setting.getSmtp());
normProps.put("mail.smtp.host", setting.getSmtp());
authProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "8025");
normProps.put("mail.smtp.port", "8025");
```

Comment: yup i know but client can change the port in the text box that provide by the system..how can i get those input to include in the code..

Comment: So you need to transfer this value from a text box to mail sending method via some variable or 'setting' object. You may think of some shared variable, that is updated when user enters the port, and read every time you need to send a mail.